# How to make HTTP request when user input something in Angular and handle the error?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am reading the doc
https://angular.io/guide/http#optimizing-server-interaction-with-debouncing to learn to send HTTP request when user input something.

I can get the code working (adapted from the example in the doc) when the REST API server is running and the response is OK. But if there is some error with the HTTP response (e.g. server is down, return code not 2xx), my code won't work. I.e. If I input something in the search input, it will try to send 1 HTTP request, and get an error, then no further HTTP request is sent.

My code snippet is as follows (only the essential code):

Component template

```html
<form>
<input (keyup)="searchRecord($event.target.value)">
</form>

Search Item detail: <p>{{ record$ | async)?.detail }}</p>
```

Component class

```js
record$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.record$ = this.searchText$.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distintUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((recordId) => this.searchService.searchRecord(recordId))
  );
}

searchRecord(searchText: string) {
  this.searchText$.next(searchText);
}
```

Search service

```js
searchRecord(recordId: string) {
  return this.http.get<{detail: string}>(this.url + '/' + recordId);
}
```

Comment: Yes? What do you expect it to do? If the server isn't working it should error right?

Comment: Or do you want [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError)?

Comment: Hey @Liam, what I want is that when error happens, it is ignored. And next HTTP request can be sent correctly. Right now if an error happens (e.g. 404 returned by server, if I input something again, the searchRecord function inside the component will be called, i.e. this.searchText$.next(searchText); is executed, but this.searchService.searchRecord is not called

Answer (score 0):

You have to Catch the error and deal with the error object.

For your case, you can use *ngIf else to deal with your err sceanrio and show a different template on error.

Component template

```
       <form>
          <input (keyup)="searchRecord($event.target.value)">
       </form>
          
        <div class="search-result-container" *ngIf=" record$ | async as records; else loadingOrError">
          
             <div *ngIf="records.length > 0" class="row align-items-center header">
                <h2 class="col-12"><span class="count">{{ records.length }} Results</span> </h2>
             </div>
          
             <ul class="search-result">
                <li *ngFor="let record of records">
                  <a (click)="onSelect(record)"><span class="record.detail">{{record.detail| titlecase}}</span></a>
                </li>
             </ul>
        </div>
          
           <ng-template #loadingOrError>
          
              <ng-container *ngIf="errorObject; else loading">
          
                <span class="error">We are having issue, plesase try again.</span>
                    <!-- {{ errorObject }}  -->
              </ng-container>
           </ng-template>
```

Component Class: Use CatchError here. Read more about [CatchError](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError)  here.

```
  

        record$: Observable<any>;
        searchResult$: Observable<record[]>;
        searchTerm: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
        errorObject = null;
        
        ngOnInit(): void {
          this.searchResult$ = this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm).pipe(
              catchError(err => this.errorObject = err)
            );
        }
        
        
        searchRecord(term: string) {
            this.errorObject = null;
            this.searchTerm.next(term);
        }

      onSelect(record: any) {
      //Deal with the logic when a record is selected.
      }
```

Component Service: Moved your logic in the service to keep the component code concise and clear.

```
     search(searchTerm: Observable<string>): any {
        return searchTerm.pipe(
              debounceTime(500),
              distinctUntilChanged(),
              switchMap(term =>
                this.http.get<{detail: string}>(this.url + '/' + term );
              );
        }
```

Comment: If you catch the error and re-throw it with `throwError`, the underlying subscriptions will still receive an error and stop listening.

Comment: Does this code work?
1. this.searchTerm is Subject<string>, but it is passed to search, which takes a string. 2. catchError takes an arrow function which returns void, which gives the error "Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<unknown>) => ObservableInput<any>'."

Comment: search should be an Observable<string>. And since, i removed the throwError(as mentioned in the above comments), had to remove the blockBodyBraces. Updated it.It shouold work now.

Comment: Thanks. However the function inside catchError should be "catchError(async (err) => console.log('Something goes wrong'))" . When I get error response, I can see the error log message, but this does not solve my problem. What I want is that after the function catchError is called, next time I input something, a new HTTP request is sent. The current code doesn't do that